# Создание списка свойств полученных из файла

Tags: c#

Вот пример файла:

> int,Id
>
> string,Nickname
>
> int,Rank

Как из этого списка получить список свойств как например такой:

```
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Nickname { get; set; }
public int Rank { get; set; }
```

Предваряя все вопросы: потом из этого списка автоматически делается таблица SQL.

Comment: Вы хотите тип на ходу сделать или присвоить значения имевшемуся типу?

Comment: И какую задачу вы решаете? Может быть проще воспользоваться DataTable?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Хочу создать свойство с нужным типом заранее. И нужно именно так. Задача создать что то типа шаблона.

Comment: И в чем смысл? Даже если вы сгенирируете типы в рантайме, то доступ к свойствам вам придется получать через рефлексию.

Comment: T4 шаблоном можно воспользовать https://developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/t4-templates-for-lookup-tables/ . Но это опять же не рантайм.

Comment: запретили использование анонимных классов или словарей?)